# CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: Error code 65

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

My app is called BookHeart. It's built by Ionic3 with "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5".

When I run "ionic cordova build ios", I got error report:

```
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform ios
[03:10:01]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0 
......
[03:10:21]  lint finished in 852 ms 
> cordova build ios
Building project: /Users/dc/bookheart/platforms/ios/BookHeart.xcworkspace
    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: device
User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/dc/bookheart/platforms/ios/BookHeart.xcarchive

Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/dc/bookheart/platforms/ios/build/device
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/dc/bookheart/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/dc/bookheart/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h

error: archive not found at path '/Users/dc/bookheart/platforms/ios/BookHeart.xcarchive'
** EXPORT FAILED **

CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,BookHeart.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/dc/bookheart/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/dc/bookheart/platforms/ios/build/device'
    at cli.catch.err (/Users/dc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

cordova build ios exited with exit code 1.
```

Please notice that there is ** EXPORT FAILED **.

Comment: Did you tried the same command but with Xcode open?

Comment: yes, I did try that.

Answer (score 7):

It will fail if connecting my iphone while running the command. Disconnect iphone, it works.

Comment: Disconnecting my phone worked. WTAF! Ugh how apple and iOS frustrate me -_-

Comment: I have the same issue do you know what cause that ?

Comment: Thank you so much! It was kind of obvious as it kept saying install ios-deploy. Here I was searching across the universe what the hell went wrong lol

Comment: You should accept your own answer so this question shows up as solved. Did the trick for me too.